# Neo4j Install APOC and Graph Algorithms Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureRegistrationFailed

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-plugin

I have some issues with APOC and Graph Algorithms plugins.
I followed the instruction to put the .jars in `{NEO4j_HOME}/plugins` and also change the setting in my `{NEO4j_HOME}/conf/neo4j.conf`

```
dbms.directories.data=/Users/mlo/neo4j-community-3.3.1/data
dbms.directories.plugins=/Users/mlo/neo4j-community-3.3.1/plugins
dbms.directories.certificates=/Users/mlo/neo4j-community-3.3.1/certificates
dbms.directories.logs=/Users/mlo/neo4j-community-3.3.1/logs
dbms.directories.lib=/Users/mlo/neo4j-community-3.3.1/lib
dbms.directories.run=/Users/mlo/neo4j-community-3.3.1/run

dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
```

A few procedures work.

```
CALL apoc.help('dijkstra')
CALL algo.list()
```

However, most of the stored procedures do not work at all.

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureRegistrationFailed
algo.unionFind is unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outside of the sandbox. Sandboxing is controlled by the dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted setting. Only unrestrict procedures you can trust with access to database internals.
algo.pageRank is unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outside of the sandbox. Sandboxing is controlled by the dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted setting. Only unrestrict procedures you can trust with access to database internals.
```

Can someone point out where goes wrong in my setting? Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
```

to:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*,apoc.*
```

and restart Neo4j service.

Comment: Add the latter, if these lines don't exist

Comment: Great solution but for me the line that worked for my error `spatial.addPointLayer is unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outsid....` was the line `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*,apoc.*,spatial.*`

Comment: When using docker, you can use : 
    --env=NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=algo.*,apoc.* \

Answer (score 5):

Following on @[bruno-peres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6835358/bruno-peres) answer, I encountered similar issues (accessing/using Neo4j APOC/Algorithms) on Arch Linux with Neo4j 3.4.0.

I use the [APOC (Awesome Procedures for Neo4j)](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) and the [Efficient Graph Algorithms for Neo4j](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms), with the
appropriately-versioned `.jar` files downloaded to my Neo4j plugins directory; i.e.,

```
/mnt/Vancouver/apps/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.4.0/plugins/apoc-3.4.0.1-all.jar
/mnt/Vancouver/apps/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.4.0/plugins/graph-algorithms-algo-3.4.0.0.jar
```

However, when I tried to run this command,

```
CALL algo.pageRank.stream('Metabolism', 'yields',
{iterations:20, dampingFactor:0.85})
YIELD node, score
RETURN node,score order by score desc limit 20
```

in my Neo4j Browser, I got this error:

```
Error: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureRegistrationFailed

Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureRegistrationFailed: algo.pageRank is
unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outside of the
sandbox. Sandboxing is controlled by the    
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted setting. Only unrestrict 
procedures you can trust with access to database internals.
```

Per the accepted answer here (SO 48773505) [Neo4j Install APOC and Graph Algorithms...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773505/neo4j-install-apoc-and-graph-algorithms-neo-clienterror-procedure-procedureregis)

I needed to make the following edits to my "neo4j.conf" file,

```
/mnt/Vancouver/apps/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.4.0/conf/neo4j.conf
```

Uncomment this line,

```
dbms.directories.plugins=plugins
```

and add/edit this line,

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.trigger.*,apoc.*,algo.*
```

**Note** (above), it appears that `neo4j.conf` accepts *one*

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=...
```

line!  Having separate lines, e.g.

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.trigger.*,apoc.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*
```

causes the `... is unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outside of the sandbox ...` error!

Finally, restart your Neo4j server/instance,

```
neo4j restart
```